# Write logs to file as system app

Tags: android

I'm running on a rooted device as a system app and executing the following command:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
```

I print the content into a file in the internal storage.
The problem is that only the logs of my app are being recorded into the file.

I have the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: That is a security feature that was introduced in Android 4.2. If you use a rooted device why don't you execute logcat with superuser permissions?

Comment: It's not a root with su unfortunatley

Comment: You said it's rooted, how can it be rooted but not have su?

Comment: There are many kinds of roots not all of them user super user

Comment: I found the answer. need to add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

Answer (score 0):

I  found the answer. You need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```